# How to send http get request to servlet from restful webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest, http, get

I am beginner in that, but
I have a restful web service and i want to send a http get request from it and handle the response in it. if any one knows how can i do this ?

i tried this :

```
    @Context private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    @Context private HttpServletContext servletContext;
```

but i want to know what's this injection will return to me? i don't understand how will get it and it's scope, and how to get the response?!

and how i will send the request?

Answer (score 0):

i found this http client apache
and here is an example for sending an Get request and getting the response

http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

```
    String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=httpClient";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

// add request header
request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response Code : " 
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

i'll try and post any helpful edits i reach, anyone have another helpfull comments or edits please do.